# Improve MySQL Union Statement

Tags: mysql, join, union

I have the following mySql statement, which I am sure can be made more efficient, I'm just not sure what would be the best way... the only difference is the equip_id that changes in the WHERE clause...

==============

```
 (SELECT 
        `receipt_ts`, 
        `driver_id`,
        `equip_id`, 
        `pos_lon`, 
        `pos_lat`, 
        `pos_timestamp`  
   FROM `log_messaging` 
  WHERE `equip_id`='207' AND `tran_type`='T.2.12.0' 
  ORDER BY receipt_ts DESC LIMIT 1 ) 

 UNION  

(SELECT 
       `receipt_ts`, 
       `driver_id`, 
       `equip_id`, 
       `pos_lon`, 
       `pos_lat`, 
       `pos_timestamp`  
  FROM `log_messaging` 
 WHERE `equip_id`='212' AND `tran_type`='T.2.12.0' 
 ORDER BY receipt_ts DESC LIMIT 1 ) 

 UNION

  (SELECT 
         `receipt_ts`, 
         `driver_id`, 
         `equip_id`, 
         `pos_lon`, 
         `pos_lat`, 
         `pos_timestamp`  
    FROM `log_messaging`
   WHERE `equip_id`='213' AND `tran_type`='T.2.12.0' 
   ORDER BY receipt_ts DESC LIMIT 1 );
```

================

I am unioning each returned row to build a dataset of max(receipt_ts) for multiple equip_id's. (I need to get the most recent positioning for the equipment.

Sometimes the query ends up being for 100+ unique equip_id's.

I am trying to make the query execute quicker than it currently is (about 7 seconds for ~100 UNIONS as above...

Point me in the right direction??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `IN` clause :

```
SELECT receipt_ts, driver_id, equip_id, pos_lon, pos_lat, pos_timestamp 
FROM log_messaging a
JOIN (SELECT c.equip_id, max(c.receipt_ts) as receipt
      FROM log_messaging c
      WHERE equip_id in ('207', '212', '213')
        AND tran_type='T.2.12.0'
      GROUP by c.equip_id) b USING(equip_id)
WHERE b.receipt = a.receipt_ts
ORDER BY a.receipt_ts
```

Note that if you really want to use the `UNION` (I don't see why you would) but want to optimize it, you could use the `UNION ALL` which would be more performent as `UNION` check datas for duplicata removal which consume more process.

Comment: WHERE equip_id in('207','212','213')  .... this is the sort of thing I was thinking of, but the way the query is setup, it only returns a single row. is there a way of making it return a row per equip_id in the list?

Comment: that doesn't do it either... now it returns all the rows matching the listed equip_ids. 

should I integrate a MAX() statement? 

something like...

WHERE equip_id in('207','212','213') 
  AND tran_type='T.2.12.0' AND receipt_ts=(SELECT MAX(receipt_ts) WHERE equip_id= ???)
  ORDER BY receipt_ts


I'm just not sure what to put in the ???'s because it needs to change for each MAX lookup.

Also, the MAX() function seems to be slow? is this the case or just my observation?

Comment: that's looking like it might do the trick, but it's returning an error of... "Unknown column 'a.equip_id' in 'where clause'"

Comment: #1111 - Invalid use of group function

Comment: it said invalid use of GROUP statement... so I took out the max() of receipt_ts.. but now it's saying #1052 - Column 'equip_id' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: Meh, we're gonna have it.. added alias.

Comment: weird. the query took 2.19 secs and returned 0 rows..  ??

Comment: Because the condition was outside of the inner query which caused the max value to be false, edited.

Comment: this is looking real good, thanks!  i am just running a few tests and the query returns rows as expected, but it takes a long time. it took 1sec for the 3 equip_id's, and it took 26 secs for a test of 8 equip_ids :s

Comment: The gap for 5 more id is pretty impressive, however I don't see how I could make it any faster.. As I said before, performance depends on many factor.  According to the benchmark your telling me, it seems like your main problem is the hardware running the server 26 seconds for 8 rows make no sense.

Comment: I updated my indexes, and now a test of 12 equip_ids takes just over 5 secs... that's still higher than I would like.

Comment: i just ran a test from within my application with 295 id's and it only took 6 secs.. i think i'm satisfied with the results... thanks for your help!

Comment: This is so far from what the question is asking (one row per condition versus all rows) that I'm surprised the OP accepted the answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff If you look at the comments, he was mostly seeking for performance. Also, if you read the second part of my answer, I also specify the `union all` possibility.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard . . . I'm referring to the `limit 1` in the subqueries.  In any case, this is definitely not a criticism of you, more of the question.  Congratulations for figuring out what the OP was really asking.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Some of the comments are deleted, but I actually realized OP did not want the `limit 1` when he told me that the query was wrong because it returned only 1. I agree that the question does not point at all to the really wanted answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use `union all` rather than `union`.  So start with this query:

```
(SELECT receipt_ts, driver_id, equip_id, pos_lon, pos_lat, pos_timestamp
 FROM log_messaging
 WHERE equip_id = '207' AND tran_type = 'T.2.12.0'
 ORDER BY receipt_ts DESC
 LIMIT 1
) UNION ALL
(SELECT receipt_ts, driver_id, equip_id, pos_lon, pos_lat, pos_timestamp
 FROM log_messaging
 WHERE equip_id = '212' AND tran_type = 'T.2.12.0'
 ORDER BY receipt_ts DESC
 LIMIT 1
) UNION ALL
(SELECT receipt_ts, driver_id, equip_id, pos_lon, pos_lat, pos_timestamp
 FROM log_messaging
 WHERE equip_id = '213' AND tran_type = 'T.2.12.0'
 ORDER BY receipt_ts DESC
 LIMIT 1
) ;
```

This is a reasonable query.  I would suggest that you create an index on `log_messaging(tran_type, equip_id, recipt_ts)`.

Comment: thanks, I switched to using UNION ALL. I already had indexes on the suggested columns.

Comment: I tried running the batch query again from my application... when 'select all' is picked, it builds a statement of 295 UNIONS (based on all of the equip_ids)... and it took 28 secs to execute.   there must be a more efficient way of putting this together?